# Definition of a submanifold

Tags: manifolds, analytic-geometry

> Say what it means for a system of equations
>
> $$f_1 = \cdots = f_m = 0,$$
>
> where $f_i(x_1, \cdots x_n)$ are differentiable functions, to define a submanifold near a point $a = (a_1, \cdots a_n), f_i(a) = 0, i = 1, \cdots m$.

From my understanding, a submanifold is patches of various surfaces put together, but I don't see how I can get that definition from this.

Comment: Do you mean to have $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ *and* $x_1,\ldots,x_m$? That means $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$. Usually, you expect $f : \mathbb{R}^{m+k} \to \mathbb{R}^m$, and $f^{-1}(0)$ is a $k$-dimensional submanifold.

Comment: @FlybyNight sorry, the $x$'s were supposed to go to $n$

Comment: Do you also want $n > m$?

Comment: @FlybyNight It doesn't say

Comment: In general, if $n < m$ then the solution to $f_1 = \ldots = f_m = 0$ will be empty. You're trying to solve $m$-equations in $n$-variables. More equations that variables is bad news. If $m=n$, the solution set will, generically, be a set of isolated points. In $n>m$ then, generically, the solution set will be a manifold of dimension $n-m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but let $\operatorname{f} : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^m$, where $n > m$. The $m$-by-$n$ [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) is given by:

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} \partial\operatorname{f}_1/\partial x_1 & \cdots &  \partial\operatorname{f}_1/\partial x_n \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\  \partial\operatorname{f}_m/\partial x_1 & \cdots &  \partial\operatorname{f}_m/\partial x_n \end{array}\right]$$

A point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is called a *regular point* if the Jacobian matrix has maximal rank, i.e. rank $m$, when evaluated at $x$. A point $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is called a *regular value* if all of the points $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for which $\operatorname{f}(x)=y$ are regular points. In such a case, the pre-image of a regular value is a smooth parametrisable manifold.

In your case, if all of the $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for which $\operatorname{f}(x)=0$ are regular points then the level-set $\operatorname{f}^{-1}(0)$ is a smooth parametrisable manifold. This is the [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

**In practise:** Find all of the $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (*critical points*) for which the Jacobian has rank less than $m$. Then find all of the images $\operatorname{f}(x)$ (*critical values*). Just check that $0 \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is *not* a critical value.

Comment: I thought the Implicit Function Theorem was just a theorem saying that you can write a multi variable function as a series of functions?

Comment: Absolutely not. It's a theorem which tells you that the pre-image of a critical value can locally be parametrised as a graph of a (multi-variable) function.